# How to select a div that contains specified class further down in the nesting?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to add styling to a div that is within a larger div structure, and for whom there exists a certain class below in the structure. The html is

```
<div class="view-content">
    <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
        <div class="ds-2col-stacked-fluid node node-lesson node-promoted node-teaser contextual-links-region view-mode-teaser teaser-layout clearfix" typeof="sioc:Item foaf:Document" about="/node/673">
            <div class="contextual-links-wrapper contextual-links-processed">
            <div class="group-header teaser-header">
            <div class="group-left teaser-left">
                <div class="field field-name-field-lessonintro field-type-text field-label-hidden">
                    <div class="field-items">
                        <div class="field-item even">
                            <p>Some text</p>
```

The classes I created are teaser-left and teaser-right. I see that the outer div containing the fields is

```
<div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
```

If I do

```
.views-row > div {
    border: 1px solid #a1c0df;
}
```

It works but that would apply to things I don't want it applied to as well. So really, I am trying to figure out a selector that would accomplish above, but only when the div contains teaser-left or teaser-right further down in the nesting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if teaser-left|right are direct children of views-row

```
.views-row > .teaser-left,
.views-row > .teaser-right {
border: 1px solid #a1c0df;
```

}

if nested more deeply

```
.views-row .teaser-left,
.views-row .teaser-right {
    border: 1px solid #a1c0df;
}
```

if applicable, the first solution is more effcicient css (renders faster), but not supported in IE6 (in case you still need that)

another option would be to create classes .views-row-teaser-left, .views-row-teaser-right and address these and only these in your css

```
.views-row-teaser-left, .views-row-teaser-right { border: 1px solid #a1c0df; }
```

this works in every browser AND is the most effcient css AND has lower specificity (which makes it easier to overrule in other style declarations and doesn't drag you into "specificity wars"). this is recommendeed if you may change the html.

Comment: In that case I will edit the module's template to allow a class of the sort you suggest. Thanks!